# In statistics, dispersion denotes how stretched or squeezed a distribution is, but what is the formal definition?

Tags: statistics, terminology

In statistics, dispersion denotes how stretched or squeezed a distribution is, but what is the formal definition by mathematical properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many measures of dispersion (scatter and other terms).

Some of the most common measures of dispersion include:

- [*Variance (Standard Deviation)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)
- Range: The range is the difference between the largest and smallest values of a distribution. Not useful if dealing with infinite quantities.
- Semi-Interquartile Range: If $\displaystyle x_{.25}$ and $x_{.75}$ represent the $25^{th}$ and $75^{th}$ percentile values, the difference $\displaystyle x_{.75} - x_{.25}$ is called the interquartile range and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left(x_{.75} - x_{.25}\right)$ is the semi-interquartile range.
- Mean Deviation: The Mean Deviation (M.D.) of a random variable X is defined as the expectation of $\left|X -\mu\right|$, that is:

$$M.D.(X) = E\left[|X -\mu|\right] = \sum |X-\mu|f(x) ~~~~\text{(discrete variable)}$$

$$M.D.(X) = E\left[|X -\mu|\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |X-\mu|f(x) dx~~~~\text{(continuous variable)}$$

Having said that, there are others too, but hopefully this gets you kick started.

Comment: Very nice, Amzoti! A great kick-start, indeed! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you, it has been TOO long! :-) I even just finished solving another nice problem.